# Open multiple firefox profiles in terminal and keep the default one profile

Tags: linux, firefox, default, profiles

I'm having a problem, when I open a firefox profile I want the next firefox I open to be in default profile and not in the last profile I open. The commands that I'm running are the this ones:

```
firefox -P sharelatex

firefox
```

I want that code to do the following

```
firefox -P sharelatex

firefox -P default
```

But instead it is doing this

```
firefox -P sharelatex

firefox -P sharelatex
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find the answer. Using `-no-remote` work well